# Laravel, can't create object with AJAX request

Tags: ajax, laravel

I'm having trouble with Laravel 5.3, in particular, with posting AJAX request data from my JavaScript, I am able to make an object but when i hit save method i get 500 (Internal Server Error).

This is my route:

```
Route::post('create_comment', 'CommentsController@ajax_store');
```

This is my controller:

```
public function ajax_store(Request $request)
{
    $comment = new Comment();
    $comment->body = $request->body;
    $comment->post_id = $request->post_id;
    $comment->user_id = auth()->id();
    $comment->save();
    return response()->json(['data' => $comment]);
}
```

This is my ajax request:

```
$('.comment-submit-button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var body = $(this).closest('form').find('textarea').val();
    var post_id = $(this).data();

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: urlCreateComment,
        data: {
            body: body,
            post_id: post_id
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data['data']);
    });
```

edit:
My import is in my index page

```
@push('scripts')
<script>
   var urlCreateComment = '{{ url('create_comment') }}';
</script>

<script src="{{ asset('/js/realtime.js') }}"></script>
<script>
   $.ajaxSetup({
       headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
       }
    });
</script>
@endpush
```

my form:

```
<form action="{{ url('create_comment') }}" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea placeholder="Write a comment ..." class="form-control" name="body" cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
    </div>
    <!-- /.form-group -->
    {{ csrf_field()  }}

    <div class="form-group adjust">
        <button data-id="{{ $post->id }}" type="submit" class="comment-submit-button">
            <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
        </button>
    </div>

</form>
```

edit: 
I get this error :
Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into `comments` ...

edit: ... i solved it, the problem was that i have to implement the get method on the request...

```
$request->get('body');
```

but now i have a new problem when i want to upload an image and i use hasFile() method via ajax with Laravel 5.3 it return null ... why?

Has anybody experience this before? Any insight and advice would really be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where is your JS variable `urlCreateComment` defined? 500 errors come with specific details, including a helpful message, so what is it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, how can i find this info?

Comment: Check your browser's developer console. Laravel by default outputs debug information about a 500 error to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

In your `JS` change the following:

```
var post_id = $(this).data(); // $request->get('post_id') will produce an array
```

To this:

```
var post_id = $(this).data('id');
```

Comment: Sheikh heera, what happened to your blog?

Comment: No its the same